# Swingx search in a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, swingx

I should want to implement a search functionality in a JTextPane. I already use swingx, and I see `Searchable` interface, with a `JXEditorPane.DocumentSearchable`. I suppose it's for JXEditorPane.

But I use a **JTextPane**. Is there some exemple with that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to reuse the search components provided by SwingX (for example the `JXFindBar`) for your `JTextPane` it is sufficient to create an implementation of the `Searchable` interface which works against your `JTextPane`. This `Searchable` instance can then be passed to the `JXFindBar`.

The `JXEditorPane.DocumentSearchable` is more or less what you want since it works against a `Document` (see [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jtstand/jtstand-desktop/1.2.1/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXEditorPane.java#JXEditorPane.DocumentSearchable)) so starting from this source code you should have your own implementation ready in a jiffy.